# How to force computer to use PPPOE connection permanently

Tags: router, isp, pppoe

How can I force a computer on my network to use my second uncapped ISP account instead of the LAN default account which is set up in the router.

I can create a PPPOE connection on the computer in question, but how do I guarantee that should it not be able to connect on the PPPOE connection, it DOES NOT fall back to the local LAN break out?

Is there some kind of software that I can install?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the computer is on the same subnet as both your "LAN default account" and PPPOE connection, then it's a matter of setting your default gateway to the PPPOE router and creating an ACL to deny access to the other one.

Or, you know, you could configure the proper routing on your firewall/router. That's what they're there for.